# Navigate between cells from a detailed view with a next and back buttons

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have a table view filled with landmarks that leads to a detailed view and i want to know how can i add a next and back button on my detailedViewController to navigate between the landmarks that i have on my tableview with out having to go back to the tableview

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your detailView in a UIPageViewController.

Then the user can swipe left and right to receive the next/previous landmark detail view, or use your buttons for navigation.

When you're instantiating the UIPVC, pass the array if landmarks used by your tableView so the UIPVC's delegate methods know how to select the next landmark.

Basically, every landmark will be a page that the user can navigate to.